# Invalid principal in policy: MalformedPolicyDocument

Tags: amazon-iam

I am getting the below error for my code in spite of the existence of roles mentioned.

```
AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
              - ec2.amazonaws.com
              - es.amazonaws.com
              - lambda.amazonaws.com
              - autoscaling.amazonaws.com
              - rds.amazonaws.com
            AWS:
              - !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${Product}${Environment}*'
              - !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/infra-${Product}${Environment}*'
          Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
```

Invalid principal in policy: "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/xxxx*" (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use wildcard in this way as  noted in section Anonymous users (public) of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html :
You cannot use a wildcard to match part of a name or an ARN.

Answer (score -1):

If you included a `Path:` property in your `AWS::IAM::Role`, then when you reference this role as a `Principal:`, then you need to include its value e.g. if `${PATH}=/myroles/` then `!Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role${PATH}${Product}${Environment}`